# Jupyter Python logo

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how to add Python logo to the top right corner of python notebooks in Jupyter ?
I see Ruby notebooks are added w/ Ruby logo automatically. 
Can this be done in Python notebooks ?

Zarak, This is what I see

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    d:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\resources
  ruby       d:\eclipse\.ipython\kernels\ruby

$ pwd
/d/Continuum/Anaconda2/lib/site-packages/ipykernel/resources

$ ls
logo-32x32.png  logo-64x64.png
```

Comment: There should be a [Python logo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter/notebook/master/docs/resources/running_code_med.png) in the top right corner. Do you not see anything?

Comment: Somehow, mine doesn't show up

Comment: Could you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the HTML and CSS of your notebook page?

Comment: Also, run the command `jupyter kernelspec list` in your shell, and navigate to the directory it shows for python. Does it contain any png files?

Comment: Zarak, added to the main question

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a solution, but an amelioration of the problem...

I had (still do) similar issue on my OS X 10.7. In my case, jupyter's python kernel, while not able to find `logo-64x64.png` file, would auto-redirect me to 404 page as soon as Notebook loads - so I was not able to use Notebooks at all.

If anyone else is having similar issue, I suggest to try any of the following steps (until you can use Notebook again). I still see `404 GET /kernelspecs/Python%20[Root]/logo-64x64.png` message in Terminal - however, now I do not get redirected to 404 page automatically upon loading the Notebook.

- initially I was using Firefox as default browser, however I switched to Chrome.
- initially I only had kernel for python2.7 installed. Now I added kernel for python3.
- I generally call jupyter with `--notebook-dir` argument. I copied into the folder I specify in that argument - the files from location, which I get by running `jupyter kernelspec list` (2 logo files and 1 json file)

In the end, I still have the same issue - and I am anxiously waiting for somebody else to respond with a solution. However, hope this helps some people in the meantime.